# A temporary profile created by service if User Profile Disk of RDS collection is enabled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I configured Remote Desktop Service on Server 2012 R2, and enabled User Profile Disk on the RDS collection.

Then I configured a Windows service and assign a user account (say MyUser) as the logon user account for the service. Then reboot the PC.

Then I login and check the user profile created for MyUser (using This PC -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> User Profiles (Settings) ). It shows that it is created as Temporary Profile. Event logs show Event ID 1511 saying that it cannot find a local profile, thus creating a temporary profile.

If I disabled the service, and login as MyUser from desktop, then a normal local profile (created as a mounted drive from UPD file) is created.

So it seems that the service cannot create a normal local profile from UPD of RDS. Is there any workaround for it ?

Comment: How is “RDS and UPD” related to a “Windows service and login account?” What critical piece of information are we missing here for any of this to make sense? Questions aren’t typically confusing if you take the time to explain what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have my RDS set up with UPD. I also have a service running with account "MyUser". Anytime I login to the system using the account "MyUser", the created profile is a temporary profile. Disabling the UPD, or disabling the service fixed the problem. However, I don't want to do either of them and looking for another workaround.

Comment: @nikoniko- I'm experiencing the same issue; did you find a resolution?

Comment: @AndrewBucklin Sorry, I didn't find any solution for this issue yet.